# Find value in column, use that information, and stop searching

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, find, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets with some information in columns and rows. I want to look for a "specific text" in the first column and write something in another tab, but I don't want to continue searching in the column. Just need to know if the specific text appears or not. Example:

```
SPOTFIRE             Peter
SMARTWEB              Mike
SMARTWEB              Mike
X9CLARA               John
```

I want to look for text `SMARTWEB` and put the word `found` in a different tab.

This is a simple script:

```
var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Sheet1 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet one");
var Sheet2 = Spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet two");
var Lastrow = Sheet1.getLastRow();
  for (var i=1; i<=Lastrow; i++){   //check all the rows of that column
    var Check = Sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    if (Check == "SMARTWEB"){  //check the cell value of each row
      Sheet2.getRange(3,1).setValue("found");  //write the text in the target cell
    }
  }
```

The problem is that this script will continue looking for `SMARTWEB` value in all of the rows. Imagine I have 10,000 rows it will take much time. I just need a script to know if "in all the column rows" I have the value `SMARTWEB`. I don't care the position or any other detail. Only know if it appears in the column and write `found` in a different sheet.

Is it possible in a more simple way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't there more specific tags for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just use a formula like this:

`=SUM(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SEARCH("SMARTWEB",Sheet1!A:A))))`

A positive number means the string exists in column A of Sheet1, whereas a zero means it doesn't

Comment: Hi Chris. Yes, that works. I wanted to use a script instead of a formula, but I can execute the formula by the script. Easier than my previous script. Thanks!